# 'stdio.h' file not found. MuPDF

Tags: iphone, shared-libraries, mupdf

All I'm trying to do is run the xcode project from this site: http://www.mupdf.com/

The problem is I get this error:

```
Shell Script Invocation Error: 'stdio.h' file not found
```

The site mentions that if I'm running from source I need to install dependencies, but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried dragging the files they said I need into xcode libraries section, but that did nothing.

Any ideas?

*EDIT* I've noticed that the libLibraries.a file is red under Targets->MuPDF->"Build Phases Link Binary with Libraries" not sure how to tell it where to find that file...

Comment: I just did a build from the latest git of mupdf with Xcode 4.5.1 on OS X 10.8.2 without seeing any errors like this. The error you get looks unrelated to the third party stuff. Have you got the command line tools installed in Xcode?

Comment: I'm using XCode 4.5.1 and OSX 10.7.4. Even downloading from GIT in the terminal I still get the same error... Do you suggest I install the command line tools in Xcode?

Comment: You need the command line tools, so install those if you haven't.

Comment: I've installed them, but I'm not sure what to do with them or even how to open them... (thank you!)